# Getting the called static class name in a stack trace

Tags: php

For my current project I've built a class that allows me to log information alongside with the current stack trace. I'm using `debug_backtrace()` to get the backtrace, but there's a "[not a bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=39111)" in it by which whenever an inherited static method is called, the backtrace mentions the name of the parent class instead of the name of the actual, called class.

If you take this example:

```
<?php
class Logger {
  public static function trace() {
    print_r(debug_backtrace());
  }
}

class Animal {
  public static function create() {
    Logger::trace();
  }
}

class Cat extends Animal {
}

class Dog extends Animal {
}

Cat::create();
```

This is the stack trace generated by `debug_backtrace()`:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [file] => /t.php
            [line] => 10
            [function] => trace
            [class] => Logger
            [type] => ::
            [args] => Array
                (
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [file] => /t.php
            [line] => 20
            [function] => create
            [class] => Animal
            [type] => ::
            [args] => Array
                (
                )

        )

)
```

You see, all I know from this backtrace is that `Animal::create()` was executed, but I don't know whether it was a `Dog` or a `Cat`, and I'm forced to look it up on the code to find out -- which is less than ideal when I'm looking at many lines of logs!

Is there a way to build a stack trace as good as `debug_backtrace()`'s but with **invoked class names** instead?

Note: I'm running PHP 5.5

Comment: I can suggest to use "Class name = file name" approach if possible.  In this case you will always have file path and could get a class name from it (Dog.php => Dog, Cat.php => Cat).

Comment: @AndreyMischenko: I do follow that approach, but in many cases this doesn't help because the child classes override properties and not methods, and thus they don't appear in the call stack (this is actually the case for many of my models, which inherit from Model and don't necessarily declare methods, only properties like table name, etc... so I  get, say, `Model::find()` in SomeController.php, then `Query->execute()` in Model.php and then `PDOStatement->execute()` in Query.php)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try to not make static calls, if needed you can use a service container to make all the dirty job for you.
A service container would make you not only get the trace correctly, but it would make your code testable aswell!!

```
class Logger {
  public function trace() {
    print_r(debug_backtrace());
  }
}

class Animal {
  public function create() {
    $logger = new Logger();
    $logger->trace();
  }
}

class Cat extends Animal {
}

class Dog extends Animal {
}

$cat = new Cat();
$cat->create();
```

With no static call, it gets me this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [file] => /home/daniel/workspace/playground/stack.php
            [line] => 11
            [function] => trace
            [class] => Logger
            [object] => Logger Object
                (
                )

            [type] => ->
            [args] => Array
                (
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [file] => /home/daniel/workspace/playground/stack.php
            [line] => 22
            [function] => create
            [class] => Animal
            [object] => Cat Object
                (
                )

            [type] => ->
            [args] => Array
                (
                )

        )

)
```

Hope this helps!